# C# .net callback'и

Tags: c#, .net, события, callback, делегаты

Здравствуйте, я забыл как объявлять `callback`'и, приведите пожалуйста пример `callback`'а, который возвращал как нибудь `String` и `TcpClient`, и собственно всё выглядело что-то типа ( а организация самого `callback`, была вынесена в другой `class`) ...

```
    Service.onRecieve += new onRecieveDelegate(onRecieve)

    private void onRecieve(TcpClient clnt, String str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User send : " + str);
    }
```

Я в интернете смотрел уже, не спорю, там много статей по этой теме, но все разные и не одна не похожа, на то как я раньше делал :(

Comment: Используйте `Action<>`

Comment: @Андрей аа, а я то думаю чего-то не хватает )) Можно по подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: не проще ли использовать какой-то ивент агрегатор ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В программировании **Callback**  - это передача исполняемого кода в качестве одного из параметров другого кода. Для этой цели C# имеет делегаты.

```
public class MyTcpClient
{
    private TcpClient _clnt;

    public MyTcpClient()
    {
        _clnt = new TcpClient();
    }

    public void DoWork(Action<TcpClient, string> callBack)
    {
        // Делаем что-то...

        // Вызываем CallBack
        callBack?.Invoke(_clnt, "Некая строка");
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new MyTcpClient();
    client.DoWork((tcpClient, s) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Получена строка {s}");
    });
}
```